# NSfetchRequest return nothing

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

When fetch data from core-database & same time update data for the same entity then fetchRequest return nil

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Abc")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@ ", productID)

    do {
        let product = try mainContext.fetch(fetchRequest).first
        return product as? Products
    } catch _ as NSError {
        //print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The entity doesn't match the cast type of the result

Either it's

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Abc")

...

do {
    let product = try mainContext.fetch(fetchRequest).first
    return product as? Abc
```

or

```
 let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Products")

 do {
    let product = try mainContext.fetch(fetchRequest).first
    return product as? Products
```

And please name entities in singular form. Semantically you cast `product as? Product`

Comment: entity name is Products not ABC

Comment: Then follow the second suggestion.